# What is purpose of Python build in `unittest.TestCase.assertEquals` field

Tags: python-3.x, deprecated, python-unittest

Using Python 3.6, PyCharm Community 2017.2.4, Win 10
I can search so I know that `unittest.TestCase.assertEquals()` is deprecated method what is ok.
What I'm curious is the first **field** what is proposed to me in PyCharm IDE when I start typing assert part for `unittest.TestCase.assert`
First on the list of code completion I see field `unittest.TestCase.assertEquals`. Hmm
Docs by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> shows

> Class attribute assertEquals of class TestCase  External documentation: http://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#unittest.case.assertEquals

Ok - link leads to main page about `unittest` framework
Lets print values:

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> import unittest
>>> unittest.TestCase.assertEquals
<function TestCase._deprecate.<locals>.deprecated_func at 0x03DAC348>
>>> help(unittest.TestCase.assertEquals)
Help on function deprecated_func in module unittest.case:
deprecated_func(*args, **kwargs)
```

So this field is reference to function what is depricated - am I understanding that right?

Comment: That's how function decoration works in Python. `deprecated_func` is a wrapper function declared inside and returned by the function decorator `_deprecate`.

Comment: @hristo-iliev thanks for answer - I don't understand this well and some examples will be fine in that case :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a short example of how function decoration works in Python. Let's have a function that returns the answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything:

```
def get_answer():
   return 42
```

If you examine the `get_answer` symbol, you'll see it's a function:

```
>>> get_answer
<function get_answer at 0x7f9c4f8bac08>
>>> get_answer()
42
```

Now let's decide that returning a hardcoded answer is not really scientific or reusable in other universes and that the function should actually compute it based on the actual parameters of the universe. So a new function `compute_answer` is introduced and `get_answer` is deprecated in favour of the new one. To warn the user of the deprecation, several things could be done:

The source code could be modified to give out a warning:

```
def get_answer():
   print("WARNING: Function get_answer is deprecated")
   return 42
```

This is ugly as it introduces changes in the source code of the function. A better way is to wrap the function:

```
def deprecated(func):
   def show_deprecated():
      print("WARNING: Function {} is deprecated".format(func.__name__))
      return func()
   return show_deprecated
```

What happens here is that we pass a function to the `deprecated` function and the latter builds and returns a wrapper. The wrapper is an instance of the nested `show_deprecated` function that captures (remembers) the value of `func` argument at the time of call. This is called *closure* and is one of the cornerstones of functional programming.

We can now route the call to `get_answer` through `deprecated` to get an automatic deprecation message without changing anything in the source code of the function:

```
>>> get_answer_dep = deprecated(get_answer)
>>> get_answer_dep()
WARNING: Function get_answer is deprecated
42
```

We can also override `get_answer` with its wrapped version so that all calls to it get routed through the wrapper:

```
>>> get_answer = deprecated(get_answer)
>>> get_answer()
WARNING: Function get_answer is deprecated
42
```

At this point one no longer has access to the original non-wrapped code of `get_answer`. It still exists and gets called by the wrapper function, but there is no publicly visible symbol that allows us to simply call it directly (it is still possible to call the original code via introspection of the wrapper, but let's pretend we don't know how to do it). If you now examine the `get_answer` symbol, it is actually an instance of the `show_deprecated` function:

```
>>> get_answer
<function show_deprecated at 0x7f9c4218b140>
```

Since `help(something)` displays the `__doc__` property of the object itself, calling `help(get_answer)` actually shows the doc-string of `show_deprecated`:

```
>>> help(get_answer)
Help on function show_deprecated in module __main__:
show_deprecated()
```

Writing `name = deprecated(name)` after each deprecated function is a bit tedious. That's why Python provides a short-cut syntax:

```
@deprecated
def get_answer()
   return 42
```

The `@deprecated` syntax is called *function decoration*. It simply instructs the interpreter to insert a call to the decorator function, in this case `deprecated()`, after the definition of the function and assign the result to the symbol bearing the function name, i.e.:

```
@foo
def bar():
   ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
def bar():
   ...

bar = foo(bar)
```

The `unittest` module is not making use of the decorator syntax as seen in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/unittest/case.py#L1316).

That `help()` shows the help of the wrapper function instead of the original one is a bummer while debugging. Fortunately, function names and doc strings are actually writeable properties and one can copy them from the original function onto the wrapper and thus preserve the name and documentation string shown by `help()`. Python comes with the `functools` module that provides the `wraps` decorator that does exactly that. The decorator is used on the nested (wrapper) function:

```
from functools import wraps

def deprecated(func):
   @wraps(func)
   def show_deprecated():
      print("WARNING: Function {} is deprecated".format(func.__name__))
      return func()
   return show_deprecated
```

If we now wrap the `get_answer` function, the name, the documentation, and the module properties are preserved:

```
 >>> get_answer = deprecated(get_answer)
 >>> help(get_answer)
 Help on function get_answer in module __main__:
 get_answer()
```

Comment: The key here is  `bar = foo(bar)` and `@wraps(func)`. Fantastic answer - sorry for late upvote and have a good day mate :)